# match the values in array with content in second array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, tuples, array.prototype.map

i am having trouble with the following:

I want to know the mean value of the positions in the first array, lets say in this case is 3. 3, then would be the position I look for in the second array and therefore will return "d" as an answer. this is my code, so far I am not even able to return the sum of the positions. Could you guys help me?!

```js
const avgPosition = (list1, list2) => {
  return (list1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0).map((element,index)=>{
    return [list2[element]]
  })
}

console.log(avgPosition(["a","b","c"],["a","b","c","d","e"]))
```

Comment: You are trying to sum strings?

Comment: not really, i am trying to get the average of the positions. meaning on the first array: a=0, b=1, c= 2; its average is 1, then posiiton of 1 in the second array would be "b" so the answer would be b.

Comment: your comment above say a different thing of what you said in the question: *"mean value of the positions in the first array, lets say in this case is 3"*... also, let's say that `list1` is `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`, the avarege index is `2.5`  which index from list2 it should return?

Comment: very good question, i would like to say that I would then be looking to round to the next integer? is that super crazy? I am learning and kind of superstuck with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this?, I'm not sure I understood your question very well but I gave it a try anyway

```js
const avgPosition = (list1, list2) => {
  if(!list1.length) return "I'm sorry I have nothing to do with an empty array!";
  let index = list1.reduce(function(a, b, c) {
    return a + c;
  }, 0) / list1.length;
  return list2[index] || `I'm confused should I pick ${list2[Math.floor(index)]} or ${list2[Math.ceil(index)]}`;
}

console.log(avgPosition([],["a","b","c","d","e"]));
console.log(avgPosition(["a","b","c"],["a","b","c","d","e"]));
console.log(avgPosition(["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d","e"]));
```